# How does VGG19 double the 64 channels to 128 channels

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

In VGG19, the number of channels after the first conv layer is 64, and then it goes to 128. I guess the 128 channels each are from a 3*3 kernel. Is it true that each of the 64 channels is convolved two times (so working with two 3*3 kernels), resulting in 2 channels? (So in total we get 2*64 = 128 channels.)

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean `3x3` instead of `33`. Here is the convolution procedure say for RGB image,

If you have an image with volume of (height, width, channels) of `(200, 200, 3)` and have `64 filters of 3x3` then each filter must be of shape `(3, 3, 3)` to convolve over `(200, 200, 3)`. **The channels must match since they will be element wise multiplied then finally all results added.**

To preserve the height and width of volume after convolution, padding is applied. Applying `(1, 1)` padding to `(200, 200, 3)` results in new volume shape of `(202, 202, 3)`.

Output of convolving single filter `(3, 3, 3)` over `(202, 202, 3)` is `(200, 200, 1)`. Then a bias is added which by broadcasting turns into shape of `(200, 200, 1)` which summing with output volume still results in `(200, 200, 1)`.

Next, if `64 filters of shape (3, 3, 3)` in convolved with padded input `(202, 202, 3)` the output result is of shape `(200, 200, 64)`. Each `(200, 200, 1)` output volume as a result of convolution is `stacked channel wise` resulting in `(200, 200, 64)`. Then bias, non-linearities etc. are applied.

#### Same applies for 128 filters to get 128 channel output,

If padded input volume is `(202, 202, 64)` and the `filter size of 3x3` then to convolve its shape must be of `(3, 3, 64)`. The result of this convolution is of dimension `(200, 200, 1)`.

Doing the same with `128 filters of (3, 3, 64)` results in output volume shape of `(200, 200, 128)`. **This way channel is set to desired number of filters.**

All strides are assumed to be `1`. `1x1` convolutions can also give desired number of output channels.

#### These are explained more clearly here with the formula,

From page 68 for convolution over volume, http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2021/lecture_5.pdf

Convolution over volume, https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/ctQZz/convolutions-over-volume

Convolution formula, https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/nsiuW/one-layer-of-a-convolutional-network

VGG architecture, https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/MmYe2/classic-networks